# Having a delayed action after clicking a form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have the following code to open a form in a popup window. I want to, after clicking the submit button, have an alert popup after 1250 milliseconds. This does not currently work as the page gets redirected to the result of submitting the form.

```
<?php
$blah = "Well"; $test = "Done";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="fetchlayers.js"></script>';
$formcode = "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data \"><label for=\"file\">Filename:</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\"/> <br /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"setTimeout(function() { alert('$blah'); },1250);\" /></form>";


echo "<h1>hello</h1>
<div id='form'>
<a href='#' onclick=\"createpopup('" . htmlentities($formcode) . "'); return false;\">
click here</a>
</div>";
```

What would be the best way to have a delayed action after submitting a form?

Answer (score 1):

try to use document.form.submit() inside the timer callback rather than using a submit button

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to open a pop-up containing a form, then after submitting the form, show an alert box?

Try using window.opener in your setTimeout() callback. This way you can tell the original window to display the alert box - it shouldn't matter that your pop-up page has been redirected.

Comment: I just sused the alart as an example, I actually want to call one of my ownmethods to update a div in the parent via ajax

Comment: using the window.opener property to reference the main window should allow you to call any function or operate on any DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to have a delayed action after submitting a form?

You simply cannot perform those two operations in that order from the same window. As soon as the form submits you are effectively leaving the state of the current page behind and asking for a new resource.

From your popup you will have a reference to the parent window. When the user wants to submit the form, you can call some JavaScript to execute a delayed action in the parent window, and then allow the form in the popup to submit.

EDIT: Based on your comment here is a way to communicate between windows; you can have a simple setup like this:

```
<!-- parent.html -->
<input type="button" onclick="doOpenChild();" value="Spawn Child Window" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function doOpenChild() {
    window.open(
      "child.html",
      "child"
    );
  }

  function doSomething() {
    setTimeout(
      function(){
        alert(fileINeedToCheck);
      },
      2000
    );
  }

  // Set variable for child to update...
  window.fileINeedToCheck = "unset";
</script>
```

Spawn a popup with something like this:

```
<!-- child.html -->
<form action="/someaction.php" name="childForm" onsubmit="communicateWithParent(this);">
  <input type="text" name="fileName" value="100" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function communicateWithParent(aForm) {
    if(window.opener) {
      if(window.opener.fileINeedToCheck) {
        window.opener.fileINeedToCheck = aForm.fileName.value;

        // You can also call functions from the parent window...
        window.opener.doSomething();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The parent window's variable can be updated with values from the child window.

Comment: I actually want to update a div in the parent window via ajax to show a list of files, and was going to give it an appropriate timewindow in which the file would have uploaded. DO you have a better way to do this?

Comment: If that's the case, there are a few things you could do. You can create a variable in your parent window and update it from the child window when the file list is ready to be updated. You can then periodically check to see if the value has changed and AJAX update you file list.

Comment: My child window simply uploads a file, and then shows the name of the file that was uploaded. The simplest way would be to update the layer by calling my js function from the php result page. Is this possible?

Comment: I updated the answer to include a "delayed" response after the child form submits. Try this out for yourself?

Comment: I think all I might have to do is call window.opener.myUpdateFunction() from the result text of submitting a file...would this be a simpler way?

Comment: That is demonstrated in my example. You are on the right track.